# Coleções - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Possuo uma coleção chamada `suspeitosSchema` e outra chamada `acoesSchema`.

**suspeitosSchema:**

```
const suspeitosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sexo: { type: String },
  etnia: { type: String },
  cumprimentoCabelo: { type: String },
  corCabelo: { type: String },
  altura: { type: String },
  peso: { type: String },
  tipoArma: { type: String },
  armaBranca: { type: String },
  armaDeFogo: { type: String },
  observacao: { type: String }
})
```

**acoesSchema:**

```
const acoesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dataCadastro: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  fonte: { type: Array, required: true },/*
  bo: { type: String },*/
  numeroBo: { type: Number, required: true },
  imagem: { type: String },
  relato: { type: String, required: true },
  modus: { type: String, required: true },
  falhasApuradas: { type: String, required: true },
  data: { type: Date, required: true }, 
  latitude: { type: String, default: '-27.226520' },
  longitude: { type: String, default: '-52.018375' },
  suspeitos: [suspeitosSchema],
  veiculos: [veiculosSchema],
  tipoAcao: { type: String, required: true, required: true }
})
```

Percebam que na coleção acoes possui um campo chamado `suspeitos`, desta forma, consigo armazenar a partir de um formulário os dados de um suspeito juntamente com o restante dos dados.

Porém, eu preciso adicionar mais de um suspeito por formulário, não estou conseguindo fazer isto, alguém tem alguma ideia de como poderia fazer?

Comment: Acho que iterando o número de suspeitos e adicionando a um array antes de armazenar em `acoesSchema` ai armazena esta array ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corriga por: `suspeitos: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'suspeitosSchema' }]`

```
const acoesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dataCadastro: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  fonte: { type: Array, required: true },/*
  bo: { type: String },*/
  numeroBo: { type: Number, required: true },
  imagem: { type: String },
  relato: { type: String, required: true },
  modus: { type: String, required: true },
  falhasApuradas: { type: String, required: true },
  data: { type: Date, required: true }, 
  latitude: { type: String, default: '-27.226520' },
  longitude: { type: String, default: '-52.018375' },
  suspeitos: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'suspeitosSchema' }],
  veiculos: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'veiculosSchema' }],
  tipoAcao: { type: String, required: true, required: true }
})
```

Comment: concordo com a resposta do @HudsonPH, se você definir que é um array de ObjectId's você poderá então usar o populate pra mostrar e, para salvar no banco só mandar os objectid's na ação.